# R: check if the column value falls between a range

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, sapply

I have two data frames.

**Frame-1**

[image: Dataframe One]

**Frame-2**

[image: Dataframe 2]

- Columns `From` and `to` of *data.frame.2* are the ranges in which column `Step` of the *data.frame.1* are present.

I want to combine these two data frames using the `Steps` with their range (`From` and `to`), and then assign them `new_id`. Both data frames have different numbers of rows.

**Example**

```
# DataFrame1
df1 <- data.frame(Step = c(1:10), id = paste0("id_", c(1:10)))

# DataFrame2
df2 <- data.frame(from = seq(1,10,2), to = seq(3,12,2), new_id = paste0("newLabel_", c(1:5)))
```

What I tried

```
df1$label <- ifelse(sapply(df1$Step, function(p) 
                 any(df2$from > p & df2$to < p)), 
                 df2$new_id, NA)
```

**Error**

I get `NAs` instead of labels.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` version >= 1.1.0, we can use non-equi join with `join_by`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = join_by(closest(Step >= from), closest(Step <= to))) %>%
   select(names(df1), new_id)
```

-output

```
 Step    id     new_id
1     1  id_1 newLabel_1
2     2  id_2 newLabel_1
3     3  id_3 newLabel_2
4     4  id_4 newLabel_2
5     5  id_5 newLabel_3
6     6  id_6 newLabel_3
7     7  id_7 newLabel_4
8     8  id_8 newLabel_4
9     9  id_9 newLabel_5
10   10 id_10 newLabel_5
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, new_id := i.new_id, on = .(Step >= from, Step <= to)]
```

-output

```
> df1
    Step    id     new_id
 1:    1  id_1 newLabel_1
 2:    2  id_2 newLabel_1
 3:    3  id_3 newLabel_2
 4:    4  id_4 newLabel_2
 5:    5  id_5 newLabel_3
 6:    6  id_6 newLabel_3
 7:    7  id_7 newLabel_4
 8:    8  id_8 newLabel_4
 9:    9  id_9 newLabel_5
10:   10 id_10 newLabel_5
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response. I have version ‘1.1.0’, but it says `Error in join_by(closest(Step >= from), closest(Step <= to)) : could not find function "join_by"`

Comment: @sp29 For me, that it working `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.1.0’`

Comment: Can you try on a fresh R session with only dplyr loaded

Comment: @sp29 if that is an issue, the data.table updated solution should have worked for you